# Using Firefox's Downloads.jsm to download file one at a time while observing them?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, download

Mozilla gave [some sample code using Firefox's Downloads.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm#Observing_downloads), I'm trying to use Downloads.jsm to download several files one at a time in a serial fashion.

But when I tried using it like this:

```
Task.spawn(function () {

  let list = yield Downloads.getList(Downloads.ALL);

  let view = {
    onDownloadAdded: download => console.log("Added", download),
    onDownloadChanged: download => console.log("Changed", download),
    onDownloadRemoved: download => console.log("Removed", download),
  };

  yield list.addView(view);
  try {
    let download = yield Downloads.createDownload({
      source: "http://www.mozilla.org/",
      target: OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.tmpDir, "example-download.html"),
    });
    list.add(download);
    download.start();
  } finally {
    yield list.removeView(view);

    moveOnToNextDownload();
  }

}).then(null, Components.utils.reportError);
```

where I move on to the next download using `moveOnToNextDownload()`, several downloads are started and files are downloaded in parallel.

How should I use Downloads.jsm to download files one at a time in a serial fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`download.start` is an asynchronous method that returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise), so `moveOnToNextDownload` is called immediately after your first download is *started*.

Instead, you can do `download.start().then(moveOnToNextDownload)`.